# Swift Networking - unable to find right information about Socket programing for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sockets, networking

I want to learn in reasonable depth iOS socket programing with SWIFT.

I tried:

1. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/) - its written for C++ and is overcomplicated (I learned Java socket programing in a week, this has so many things that are unnecessary)
2. Searched the forums on Stack, but looks like everyone is doing something different with CF or NS libraries.
3. This resource: http://swiftrien.blogspot.com/2015/10/socket-programming-in-swift-part-2.html - simply for me its overcomplicated.
4. Ray Wenderlich in https://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server - is again doing C++ and is using 3rd party

and so on...

Is there some holly grail that has simple syntax like in Java, or am I doomed to work with some C++ things in my Swift code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=socket+swift is there something interesting avaiable?

Comment: Did you try https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html ?

Comment: Typically you would use a framework such as AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket. This a cross platform framework for doing socket level programming in Swift.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that everyone is doing something like this or AFNetworking. I guess I have to move away to 3rd party... 
Its programer maturing... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use a socket framework to start with.

[SwiftDSSocket](https://github.com/csujedihy/SwiftDSSocket) is a framework written in pure Swift and I actively maintain this framework. It has really simple API and documents available as well as Demo.